# Simple Coding Issue with HTML/CSS Caption within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could somebody please take a look at this livelink of my web page? I have a caption in the top right hand side of each of the divs in my layout div, however I have one horizontal box (the first one) where the caption extends to the bottom of the div instead of only having a height of 20px. I have been searching through this code but I can not see why.

Thanks in advance

***HTML***

```
 <div class="col">
    <div class="trigger vertical img1">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent">
            <div class="slider static">
                <div class="just_text">
                    <div class="caption-box">Caption</div>
                    <img src="slide1.png" height="400" width="200" />
                </div>
                <div class="just_text">
                    <div class="caption-box">Caption</div>
                    <img src="slide2.png" height="400" width="200" /></div>
                <div class="just_text">
                    <div class="caption-box">Caption</div>
                    <img src="slide3.png" height="400" width="200" /></div>
                <div class="just_text">
                    <div class="caption-box">Caption</div>
                    <img src="slide4.png" height="400" width="200" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.caption-box {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
height: 20px;
width:100px;
background-color: red;
color: #fff;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: your link is on you pc and can not be accessed by us

Comment: please create a fiddle to reproduce the issue (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: putting your code in a fiddle doesn't produce your issue, suggesting it's some css elsewhere

Comment: sorted the livelink my apologies its been a long long day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add !important to your height, this will fix it...

```
.caption-box {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
height: 20px!important;
width:100px;
background-color: red;
color: #fff;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've a

```
.trigger.vertical * {
    height: 400px;
}
```

in your CSS, that force the heigh of the caption to 400px.

It happens only to the first caption because only the first caption is a child of a .trigger.vertical

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the element with Chrome shows that the height of 20px is overridden by this CSS class:

```
.trigger.vertical * {
  height: 400px;
}
```

I noticed that there are quite a few differences in the layout between IE11 and Chrome 41.0.2272.118 so there are likely other issues with the layout.

Comment: how would you go about fixing this?

Comment: By removing the height from .trigger.vertical css  or as suggested by Dave Burns add !important to the height.